# multi authentication in 2 tables

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin

I have 2 tables in Laravel project database storing users: one is "admins" and other is "users". When I open the link "www.mysite.com/admin/login" I cannot login with admin email and password, but i can do that with any user email and password from both links "www.mysite.com/admin/login" and "www.mysite.com/login". I don't know where is the problem as I'm trying to get the multi Authentication but still there.

Comment: You mean you have two separate urls or two separate user database tables?

Comment: two urls one for users in the frontend and the other form admins in the backend

Comment: and tow tables in data base one for admins the oher for users

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M